# The usage of "it" after verbs

Tags: verbs, grammaticality-in-context

> -Do you speak German?
>
> -I speak **it** quite well.

Is the usage of **it** as a substitute for **german** grammatical?

Does providing context make a difference?

Does it sound off to the native ear?

Is there a special category of verbs that accept the word **it** after them?

Comment: In English, names of languages and adjectives of nationality start with a capital letter, so you should write "German".

Answer (score 2):

The exchange

> -Do you speak German?
>
> -I speak it quite well.

Is quite grammatical and seems fully natural to me. The use of a pronoun, such as 'it' to refer to a noun or noun phrase in a previous sentence is very common. Without the question, the answer is unclear as the pronoun lacks a referent. Similar exchanges, such as:

> -Can you play the piano?
>
> -Yes, I can play it well.

are also common, natural and fully grammatical.

Any transitive verb may be followed by an object, and a pronoun my generally be used for such an object. In addition, a pronoun may be used in other places where a noun is expected, and may have an antecedent in a previous sentence, as long as the reference is clear.